# How can I pass parameters from RootPageMenuItem to Constructer of Content Page?

Tags: xamarin.forms, master-detail

I have a problem. My Problem is I can not pass parameters from RootPageMenuItem to Constructer of Content Page.

my code:

```
new RootPageMenuItem { Id = 4, Title = "myTitle", ImageSource = "rightArrow.png", TargetType = typeof(myContentPage) },
```

I want to achieve this:

```
new RootPageMenuItem { Id = 4, Title = "myTitle", ImageSource = "rightArrow.png", TargetType = typeof(myContentPage(_param1,_param2)) },
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
if(item.TargetType == typeof(myContentPage))
{
    //This will create instance of the page using the parameterized constructor you defined in each DetailPages
Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType, param1 ,param2));
}
else
{
    Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
}
```

Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48003883/how-to-pass-string-data-from-master-detail-page-in-xamarin-forms) which you can refer .

Comment: Happy coding :)